# Is the commutative law of multiplication (used to calculate the mean) valid for all or any Likert scales?

Tags: t-test, likert

The mean score on a Likert scale is often used as the input for a t test, and the mean is mathematically meaningful so long as the axiomatic laws of arithmetic apply. For example, one response such as "strongly agree" (which might be rated 3 on a Likert scale) would be equal to three responses "slightly agree" (rate 1 on the scale) if the commutative law of multiplication was valid.

Comment: It is usually not a good idea to assign numerical values to ordinal (Likert scale) data if you do not have a strong justification for doing so. The reason for this is that you assume that you know the "distance" between two values on the scale. Is "strongly agree" really the same distance from "agree" as "neutral" is from "disagree"? I would not think so in most instances.